# storing value behind the malloced and aligned pointer C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc

Reference code : https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/02/22/generating-aligned-memory/

```
void * aligned_malloc(size_t align, size_t size)
{
    void * ptr = NULL;
    
    // We want it to be a power of two since
    // align_up operates on powers of two
    assert((align & (align - 1)) == 0);

    if(align && size)
    {
        /*
         * We know we have to fit an offset value
         * We also allocate extra bytes to ensure we 
         * can meet the alignment
         */
        uint32_t hdr_size = PTR_OFFSET_SZ + (align - 1);
        void * p = malloc(size + hdr_size);

        if(p)
        {
            /*
             * Add the offset size to malloc's pointer 
             * (we will always store that)
             * Then align the resulting value to the 
             * target alignment
             */
            ptr = (void *) align_up(((uintptr_t)p + PTR_OFFSET_SZ), align);

            // Calc`enter code here`ulate the offset and store it 
            // behind our aligned pointer
            *((offset_t *)ptr - 1) = 
                (offset_t)((uintptr_t)ptr - (uintptr_t)p);

        } // else NULL, could not malloc
    } //else NULL, invalid arguments

    return ptr;
}
```

I do not understand how this line stores value behind the ptr.
"*((offset_t *)ptr - 1) =
(offset_t)((uintptr_t)ptr - (uintptr_t)p);"

Comment: Consider the standard function `*aligned_alloc()` instead of `malloc()`.

Comment: `p` is `malloc()` base address; find out how much space is between `ptr` & `p` by doing `ptr - p`. Give some valid values for `align` & `size` to figure out how that space is formed.

Answer (score 0):

After the allocation and calculation, `ptr` contains the value this routine will return to its caller, which is the address for the caller to use to store its data.

`(offset_t *)ptr` converts this address to the type `offset_t *`.

Then `(offset_t *)ptr - 1` calculates a location in memory that is earlier (lower addressed) by the distance of one `offset_t` object.

Then `*((offset_t *)ptr - 1) = …;` stores a value in that location.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other good answers:

`ptr = (void *) align_up(((uintptr_t)p + PTR_OFFSET_SZ), align);` lays the seeds for *undefined behavior* (UB) as `aligned_malloc()` does not certainly meet `max_align_t`.

`malloc()` always provides a pointer that meets this requirement of aligning to at least `sizeof(max_align_t)` and much code relies on that.  `aligned_malloc()` does **not** certainly meet that - it should.

Do not recommend this code "as is" for portability.

To do this right, `aligned_malloc()` and `align_up()` must consider the maximum of both `max_align_t` and `size`.

```
void * aligned_malloc(size_t align, size_t size) {
  assert(...);
  if (size < sizeof(max_algin_t)) {
    size = sizeof(max_algin_t);
  }
  ...
```